# When to use UILayoutPriority = .required in setContentCompressionResistancePriority(_ priority: UILayoutPriority, for axis: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis)

Tags: ios, constraints

As per my understanding consider there are two labels if we set

```
label1.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal) 
label2.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

then label1 content will truncate if necessary. I want to know when to use .required as there is little explanation in apple documentation.

> ```
> type Property required A required constraint.
>
> static let required: UILayoutPriority 
> Discussion Do not specify a layout constraint that exceeds this number.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The value for `UILayoutPriority` can range from `0` to `1000`. These constants are provided for convenience:

```
.required    == 1000
.defaultHigh ==  750
.defaultLow  ==  250
```

You can specify other values as well. Examples:

```
let p: UILayoutPriority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 251)
let p: UILayoutPriority = .defaultHigh + 1  // == 751
let p: UILayoutPriority = .required - 1     // == 999
```

For your *specific* scenario, there is no difference between:

```
label1.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal) 
label2.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)

// or

label1.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal) 
label2.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

// or

label1.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required - 1, for: .horizontal) 
label2.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
```

and so on. As long as the priority for `label1` is less than `label2`, `label1` will compress first.

When the actual values come into play, or when you might want to use `.required`, is when they interact with **other** elements.